# MySQL selecting max record in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I am trying to create a query in a table that has some 500,000 records and some 50 or 60 columns. What I need is to collate these records into groups and select the max record in each group.

To simplify the problem I have a table as follows

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
| id | external_id | group_id | mypath |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1003 |        1 | a      | 
|  2 |        1004 |        2 | b      | 
|  3 |        1005 |        2 | c      | 
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
```

The simple group by is as follows

```
select * from temp GROUP BY group_id
```

which returns

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
| id | external_id | group_id | mypath |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1003 |        1 | a      | 
|  2 |        1004 |        2 | b      | 
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
```

Nice but not what I want. What I want is the entire record for max enternal_id in each group. In other words

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
| id | external_id | group_id | mypath |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1003 |        1 | a      | 
|  3 |        1005 |        2 | c      | 
+----+-------------+----------+--------+
```

Somehow I am looking to put a max(external_id) statement in here to filter what is needed but so far all my investigation has failed. Some guidance would be appreciated. It is important that when returning the max(external_id) that the entire record is selected as the path column differs.

Comment: Perhaps using "select MAX(external_id) AS maximum,* from temp GROUP BY group_id" you can do this.

Answer (score 19):

Much info at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

This has always been an annoying issue in MySQL.  There have been ways around it, such as concatenating several fields together (starting with external_id), and then selecting the MAX() of that, and then breaking it back apart.

I suggest you use a derived table.  First table (t1) is derived from a simple query where you identify the `MAX(external_id)`, then you join from that to get the rest of the data.

**THIS IS ONLY IF `external_id` IS UNIQUE**

```
SELECT 
   t1.group_id, some_table.id, some_table.mypath
FROM 
   (
      SELECT group_id, MAX(external_id) AS external_id
      FROM some_table
      GROUP BY group_id
   ) as t1
INNER JOIN 
   sometable ON t1.external_id = sometable.external_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yes you are quite right. Changing the problem is the best way, I should have followed the rule "if you have a problem you can't solve, change it to one you can". With suitable indexes it works well.

Comment: Minor question, but is there a reason you chose to select t1.group_id instead of some_table.group_id? Is it more efficient?