# Left joining only one result of corresponding table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

`products:
id INT
title VARCHAR`

`offers:
id INT
product_id INT
price INT`

A product can have many offers. I need to get all products with the corresponding offers with lower and higher prices, what I have is:

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, lowOffer.price, highOffer.price
FROM products

LEFT JOIN (SELECT offers.product_id, MIN(offers.price) AS price FROM offers GROUP BY offers.product_id) AS lowOffer ON (lowOffer.product_id = products.id)


LEFT JOIN (SELECT offers.product_id, MAX(offers.price) AS price FROM offers GROUP BY offers.product_id) AS highOffer ON (highOffer.product_id = products.id)
```

Now, I'm doing two subqueries, and I think I could have only one, because the two joins are working on the same set of offers. How can I do this?

My business logic is a little more complicated than this and the offers itself have relations and I'm gonna have to bring them too. How can I do this in a efficient way? I don't want to make the joins without needing to.

Comment: Have you measured that there would be a problem with the join happening? How many rows are in the mentioned tables? Normally efficient indexing should be quite enough.

Comment: I haven't made any measurements yet, but 1M+ rows should be the case in each tabl. Offers also have belongsTo relations of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join, and then use `GROUP BY` on the top level:

```
SELECT
    p.id
,   p.title
,   MIN(o.price) as min_price
,   MAX(o.price) AS max_price
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN offers o ON o.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
```

Comment: What if I needed to also find the ID of the min_price and max_price records?

Comment: @lucaswxp That would be a different query. Here is [a Q&A discussing this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12699799/335858). In general, though, when you want the record, not only the aggregate, you do a different query - in your case, there would be two subqueries that sort by price and limit result count to 1.

Comment: Hmm.. So if I understood correctly, I can't scape the two subqueries? Off-topic: is this a design problem of how SQL languages work or is just a MySQl thing..? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @lucaswxp If you need the IDs, you would end up with two subqueries. This is the way the `GROUP BY` of SQL works. To MySQL's credit, it's the most lenient of the "big" SQL engines when it comes to `GROUP BY`, because it lets you select fields not included in the list of `GROUP BY` columns.